# Is there a way to temporarily block access to a removable drive while my program is scanning it? (C++, Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, memory, locking, drive

I have a windows service written in c++ which , on demand, perform an operation (a scan) on a removable drive.
My question is, is there way to prevent the user to use the drive yet until my operation is fulfilled?

So far I have tried several methods but with no success
I tried to open a handle to the volume with share mode 0, but my operation calling the filesystem::directory_iterator results with Access Denied.

**LockFile()** does lock only a range of bytes and can't be used with a directory or volume

I am wondering if it is possible to achieve the requirement without using any driver